# Generating external id from id in play framework 2

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

Using Play Framework 2 I need to generate a unique ID based on the models' ID for the outside world (don't want to expose the models' real ID).
How can it be done using Ebean or otherwise?

For example my model is:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    //Generate unique id based on id, for the outside world
    public Long externalId;
}
```

Comment: this externalId is just for display purpose?

Comment: It's for display in URL and to refer the User when request comes from a web page.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use `id` represented in binary or HEX.

But what you probably want to achieve is to hide the magnitude of growth of your id. If yes then your choice is UUID: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Also have a look at this example app: https://github.com/jamesward/play2-ebean-uuid

Comment: Thanks, I looked into the example in the link. I see that they use an @Id of type UUID but this id is being exposed to the client. I want to use an id for the application (internally) and a different one for external use. When a client provides me with this external id, i need to be able to find the entity by this external id. I assume this kind of separation provides more security to an application.

Comment: Ok. So what stops from using normal internal id as a primary key and another unique field with UUID?

Comment: That an Id is handled by DB and is thread safe while UUID is not thread safe as far as I know.
Is there a way to make sure it's thread safe?
Making it synchronized will create substantial performance issues no?